# STDOUT not sending all data over socket in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, unix, stdout

I am new to socket programming in C++ and UNIX. I am working on a simple server and client program. The client program reads in data from a .txt file that contains a host and a number of pings to send. The client sends the line to the server where the server parses the line and runs the ping command. Then the server sends the output back to the client. The problem I am having is that the server is only sending 2 lines of the ping output and not the whole thing. I'm not sure if its a problem in my server code or client code.

**Server Code:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sysexits.h>

using namespace std;
#define MAXLINE 2048 /*max text line length*/
#define LISTENQ 8 /*maximum number of client connections */

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int listenfd, connfd, n;
  socklen_t clilen;
  char buf[MAXLINE];
  struct sockaddr_in cliaddr, servaddr;
  int portNumber = atoi(argv[1]);
  char *ch;
  char hostName[50];
  char pingsToSend[50];
  char *pingArgArray[5];
  pid_t cpid;
  int status;
  int i;

  //creation of the socket
  listenfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  //preparation of the socket address
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(portNumber);

  bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

  listen(listenfd, LISTENQ);

  printf("%s%d\n","Server - Start with Port=",portNumber);
  printf("%s%d\n","\tThe server PID is:",getpid());

  for ( ; ; ) {
    clilen = sizeof(cliaddr);
    connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &clilen);

    while ( (n = recv(connfd, buf, MAXLINE,0)) > 0)  {
      printf("\n%s","Server - Input Data received: ");
      puts(buf);

      //Parse each line of input file
      ch = strtok(buf, " ");
      strcpy(hostName,ch);
      ch = strtok(NULL, " ");
      strcpy(pingsToSend,ch);

      //Get rid of deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' error
      string binCommand = "/bin/ping";
      string dashC = "-c";
      char * arrayBinCommand = new char [binCommand.length()+1];
      strcpy(arrayBinCommand,binCommand.c_str());
      char * arrayDashC = new char [binCommand.length()+1];
      strcpy(arrayDashC,dashC.c_str());

      //Array of arguments to pass to execv
      pingArgArray[0] = arrayBinCommand;
      pingArgArray[1] = hostName;
      pingArgArray[2] = arrayDashC;
      pingArgArray[3] = pingsToSend;
      pingArgArray[4] = NULL;

      if (cpid == 0){
        fprintf(stdout,"Server - Fork child process");
        fprintf(stdout,"\nServer - Sent results of the ping comand to the client via socket");
        close(listenfd);
        dup2(connfd,STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(connfd,STDERR_FILENO);
        close(connfd);
        execvp(pingArgArray[0],pingArgArray);
      }
    }

    if (n < 0) {
      perror("Read error");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
  //close listening socket
  close(listenfd);
}
```

**Client Code:**

```
﻿#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
using namespace std;

#define MAXLINE 2048 /*max text line length*/
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int sockfd;
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
  char sendline[MAXLINE], recvline[MAXLINE];
  int portNumber = atoi(argv[2]);
  int serverIp = atoi(argv[1]);
  string line;
  ifstream pingArgumentsIn("pingData.txt");

  //basic check of the arguments
  if (argc !=3) {
    perror("Usage: TCPClient <IP address of the server> <port # of the server>");
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("%s%d%s%d\n","Client - Start with IP=",serverIp," and Port=",portNumber);
  printf("%s%d\n","\tThe client PID is:",getpid());

  //Catch error if file is not found or cant be opened
  if (!pingArgumentsIn){
    cout << "File could not be opened\n";
    return 0;
  }

  //Create a socket for the client
  //If sockfd<0 there was an error in the creation of the socket
  if ((sockfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) <0) {
    perror("Client - Problem in creating the socket");
    exit(2);
  }

  //Creation of the socket
  memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr= inet_addr(argv[1]);
  servaddr.sin_port =  htons(portNumber); //convert to big-endian order

  //Connection of the client to the socket
  if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))<0) {
    perror("Client - Problem in connecting to the server");
    exit(3);
  } else {
    printf("\n%s", "Client - Connected to server");
  }

  while (getline(pingArgumentsIn,line)){
    printf("\n%s%s","Client - Input data is: ",line.c_str());
    printf("\n%s", "Client - Sending input data to the server");

    send(sockfd, line.c_str(), strlen(line.c_str()), 0);

    if (recv(sockfd, recvline, MAXLINE,0) == 0){
      //error: server terminated prematurely
      perror("Client - The server terminated prematurely");
      exit(4);
    }
    printf("\n%s", "Client - Received output from the server via socket: ");
    printf("\n");
    fputs(recvline, stdout);

  }
  exit(0);
}
```

Here is a look at the current output I am getting:

```
Client - Received output from the server via socket:
PING www.google.com (172.217.12.68) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from dfw28s05-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.12.68): icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=1.92 ms
```

When this is what im expecting:

```
Client - Received output from the server via socket:
PING www.google.com (172.217.12.68) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from dfw28s05-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.12.68): icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=1.96 ms
64 bytes from dfw28s05-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.12.68): icmp_seq=2 ttl=48 time=1.99 ms
64 bytes from dfw28s05-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.12.68): icmp_seq=3 ttl=48 time=1.91 ms
64 bytes from dfw28s05-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.12.68): icmp_seq=4 ttl=48 time=1.96 ms
64 bytes from dfw28s05-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.12.68): icmp_seq=5 ttl=48 time=1.96 ms

--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.915/1.959/1.992/0.054 ms
```

Comment: `send(sockfd, line.c_str(), strlen(line.c_str()), 0);`will send however much can fit into the TCPIP buffer - not all of it.  You need to call send in a loop and check the return value of send until it has sent all the data.  The same is true of `if (recv(sockfd, recvline, MAXLINE,0) == 0){` it will return one buffer of info - not all the info.  You need to call it in a loop until you receive all of it.  The only reason `while ( (n = recv(connfd, buf, MAXLINE,0)) > 0)  {` works is because the thing you are trying to receive is small but really you should be calling that in a loop as well.

Comment: Unrelated: Save yourself a bit of work: strlen(line.c_str()) is, or should be, `line.size()`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Thanks for helping me understand that. Do I need to get rid of the `dup2(connfd,STDOUT_FILENO); dup2(connfd,STDERR_FILENO);` to do this? Should the send loop be in the fork or after it?

Comment: I don't think you need to change the redirection code at all - it's where the result is received in the client that needs a loop around recv().

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I think I have got the issue fixed with the output on the client. A new problem has come up now where the server exits after running one ping command. Can you tell in my code whats causing it to exit before processing the other ping commands?

Comment: "The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image. " So when you do execvp your program doesn't exist any longer - and when ping finishes the program is over.  To keep your program running while you replace a second copy of your program with ping you need to fork() the process.